# docker-compose opening storage failed: permission denied error on running

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana, prometheus

I'm trying to execute my `docker-compose.yml` file which contains prometheus and grafana configurations.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    volumes:
      - /prometheus:/prometheus
    command: 
      - --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml 


  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/grafana:/var/lib/grafana
```

Whenever I enter `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up` command to run it, I face with these kind of errors about permission:

```
prometheus_1  | level=error ts=2019-06-30T16:14:42.690Z caller=main.go:723 err="opening storage failed: lock DB directory: open /prometheus/lock: permission denied" 
prometheus_1  | level=error ts=2019-06-30T16:26:11.897Z caller=main.go:723 err="opening storage failed: mkdir data/: permission denied"
```

I don't know how to solve this problem, I already have searched over github issues and the other stackoverflow's questions, but unfortuntely none of them help!

Comment: I don't know anything about prometheus and grafana, but, to me, this looks like problem with your volume. You set volume of prometheus images to /prometheus. So you should check if your user has permission set for that dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need access from the host to these volume files, use a named volume instead of a host mount. Docker will initialize the contents of the named volume, including the permissions and ownership, avoiding permission issues like this:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  prometheus:
  grafana:

services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    volumes:
      - prometheus:/prometheus
    command: 
      - --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml 

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - grafana:/var/lib/grafana
```

---

For a general solution to solve permission issues with host mounts, the fix-perms script in my [docker-base](https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-base) image can be used, along with an entrypoint and changes to how the container is started, to dynamically adjust the userid inside the container to match that of the volume mount.

Comment: Wow! I have searched so many sites but your solution is the best! Thank you very very much man :) <3

Answer (score 2):

My `docker-compose up` command continually returned the following:

```
err="opening storage failed: lock DB directory: open /prometheus/lock: permission denied"
```

The problem is the folder structure/files on your local machine have the incorrect file permissions and when the docker container is fired up it is unable to write to the specified location.

I fixed this by recursively chown-ing the folder with the following command:

```
sudo chown -R nobody:nogroup <local path>
```

an example, my volumes section in my docker-compose.yml looked like this:

```
volumes:
  - /home/user/docker-volumes/prometheus:/prometheus
```

The colon signifies the separation of local file path : docker container file path.  Applying my previous chown example above results in the following:

```
sudo chown -R nobody:nogroup /home/user/docker-volumes/prometheus
```

My `docker-compose up` no longer fails with permission denied!

Comment: Yeah it help a lot. Thanks for your comment Christian! :*